# how do I read the oldest record in apache kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am using sparkstreaming to consume from Kafka ,think if some crash or similar happened on the consumer side. I am not worried about duplicating records , but I cannot miss even a single record. 
If I restart my consumer I would not be continuing from where I left. I guess by checkpointing I can do that?? I dont know. 
But in worst case I would like to check the possibility of running my consumer from oldest record in the kafka topic.

Comment: If it crashes, I don't think it should commit the consumed offset back to Kafka

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the offsets in kafka with the consumer group I'd. It should consume messages from start automatically. The below command might help you.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group my-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest --all-topics --execute
```

**Edit 1**: if you would like to reset offsets of only a specific topic you may do so by replacing `--all-topics` with `--topic <topicname>`

**Edit 2**: Not to forget. The `auto.offset.reset` consumer config should be set to `earliest`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing `--all-topics`

Comment: You can also reset offsets of specific topic by replacing --all-topics with --topic <topicname>